# Github actions gpg decrypt results in an error (gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.)

Tags: gnupg, github-actions

I'm building an Android apk using Github actions, and I need to use the Android sign key in order to sign it before releasing it.

To do so I'm using the technic described [here](https://medium.com/@StefMa/how-to-store-a-android-keystore-safely-on-github-actions-f0cef9413784) with GPG to encrypt the release key as base64 string, and use it as a secret in Github actions.

Then, inside my workflow, I use GPG to decrypt it back into the key file.

However, this process that works fine on my mac, is failing in Github actions.

Running this

```
- name: Decode keystore file
      run: |
        echo "${{ secrets.KEY_STORE }}" > release.keystore.asc
        gpg -d --passphrase "${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSPHRASE }}" --batch release.keystore.asc > signing-key.jks
```

results in this

```
gpg: directory '/home/runner/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/home/runner/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error
##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Running `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates` before using GPG is at no help either, since it says that it's already installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It seems `release.keystore.asc` contains invalid PGP data or no data at all. First, I would check the content of a `release.keystore.asc`. You can upload the file as an artifact then download it to examine its contents. Modify the workflow by adding the [`upload-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) action step after *Decode keystore file* step

```yaml
- name: Decode keystore file
  run: |
    echo "${{ secrets.KEY_STORE }}" > release.keystore.asc
    gpg -d --passphrase "${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSPHRASE }}" --batch release.keystore.asc > signing-key.jks
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  if: failure()
  with:
    name: release.keystore.asc
    path: release.keystore.asc
```

Now you can [download](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/persisting-workflow-data-using-artifacts#downloading-or-deleting-artifacts) the `release.keystore.asc` artifact (it will be zipped so you have to unzip it) and check if the file contains valid PGP data (the file should start with `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` and end with `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----` and contain valid encrypted PGP content between). If it does not then it means `KEY_STORE` secret contains invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error. I made a silly mistake, not sure if you also made same.
while copying the base 64 key store string to git secret, I was only copying the base64 string and not the whole file. i.e.
whole .asc file is like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
**base64 string here**
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

You need to copy this **whole** file content (including BEGIN PGP and END PGP message). This solved my problem.